# SQL Server Serverless - Openrowset - Metadata functions?

Tags: sql, metadata, azure-synapse, openrowset

I am using Openrowset with OpenJson to query files in a data lake using a Synapse SQL Serverless database.

I have found the filename() and filepath() file metadata functions.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/synapse-analytics/sql/query-specific-files#filepath

Are there more functions or is that it?
I would really like to be able to get the **file modified timestamp**.

Comment: As far as I can tell, those are the only two, which makes sense as they are both based on the object name and not the underlying metadata.

Comment: Have you got any solution for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

File metadata features are not supported via serverless function.

You should use Synapse spark notebook to query the blob metadata instead. You can find more information at [BlobProperties Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/python/api/azure-storage-blob/azure.storage.blob.models.blobproperties?view=azure-python-previous&viewFallbackFrom=azure-python)